# I'm trying to use openPose to track if I am squatting and if I am it presses the 'w' key but I keep getting an error

Tags: python, opencv, openpose

Here is my bug. I have made sure openpose is installed correctly.

```
poses = posenet.estimate_poses(frame)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'posenet' has no attribute 'estimate_poses'
```

Here is my code:

```
import posenet
import cv2

# Create a webcam object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Start the webcam
while True:
    # Get the current frame from the webcam
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Use PoseNet to track the pose of your body in the frame
    poses = posenet.estimate_poses(frame)

    # Check if you are doing a squat
    for pose in poses:
        # Get the position of your hips and knees
        left_hip = pose['keypoints'][11]
        right_hip = pose['keypoints'][12]
        left_knee = pose['keypoints'][13]
        right_knee = pose['keypoints'][14]

        # Check if your hips are higher than your knees
        if (left_hip['y'] > left_knee['y']) and (right_hip['y'] > right_knee['y']):
            # If you are doing a squat, press the w key
            cv2.waitKey(100)
            cv2.putText(frame, "Squat!", (10, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # Display the pose of your body on the screen
    cv2.imshow("PoseNet", frame)

    # If the user presses the Esc key, stop the program
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

# Release the webcam
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How did you install the posenet?

Comment: pip install posenet

Comment: that's right, but then there is no such method as estimate_poses() in posenet. If you explore the internal modules of this package, you won't see it there.